# CSS minimize window changes appearance

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my menu. When i change browser window size my menu changes from horizontally to vertical.Is any option to make a text static in the window? I want my menu to stay in same condition even if i change window size. Here's my code:

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 288px;
  margin-left: 378px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav>ul>li {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
}

nav>ul>.current-item>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="current-item"><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you add the html-markup as well?

Comment: Remove the `margin` from your `nav` tag, it's restricting the width of the `ul` which is causing the `li`s  to wrap.

Comment: doesn't work...same problem

Comment: fix the width of nav or add min-width ..... nav {min-width:600px;}

Answer (score 0):

You could add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `nav` property as in the example below:

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 288px;
  margin-left: 378px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

A couple other ways to do it:

- Add `display: inline-block` to the `nav` property.
- Set a magic number (a defined number) for the length of your navigation menu in your `nav` property (something like `width: 650px;` or `min-width:650px;` as an example) so the browser doesn't affect it.  This option is usually not considered a good practice, but this can be overlooked depending on the needs of your project.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a possible solution based on your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/zmh7tyj6/

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 288px;
  margin-left: 378px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav>ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 650px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
}

nav>ul>.current-item>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

But, I recommend something like that, much more elegant.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/tenueqe6/

Answer (score 0):

use min-width in nav for example min-width:12OOpx;

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  float:right; // float is cleaner
  width: 650px; // set to your values
  min-width: 650px; // set to your values
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Demo:

```css
nav {
  float:right;
  width: 650px;
  min-width: 650px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav>ul>li {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
}

nav>ul>.current-item>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="current-item"><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

There's a few ways to do this; ultimately you'll need to define your `width:`'s. Also, `position: absolute;` is usually not necessary for stuff like this; you can `margin:` floats as well.